# How do I load libcocos2d.a (or any static library) into MacRuby?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, libraries, macruby, .a

I tried framework and require, both with paths, and got the same library not found message.

I found an article on generating BridgeSupport files for static C libraries. I've never done this before, so will try it and report back.

But if anyone has any experience either loading cocos2d or even a custom static library, it would be appreciated.

thanks.

http://www.macruby.org/trac/wiki/MacRubyTutorial#AccessingStaticAPIs
http://bridgesupport.macosforge.org/trac/

Comment: The answer is, I think, to create an Objective-C bundle for MacRuby, per this article [https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Loading-Objective-C-Frameworks-and-Bundles](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Loading-Objective-C-Frameworks-and-Bundles) I will explore this more when I get back, but now I am out of the country for a week with only an iPad, so...more when I get back... but there's no reason it shouldn't work that I can tell--at least the calls should work.